# Open a tabbed window in Chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is there a way to open a tabbed window(a window with tabs) in Chrome using javascript?

When I open a new window with the following:

```
window.open( "http://google.com", "Google", "width=800,height=600" );
```

the window has no tabs, like so:

[image: Tabless window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no, if you call window.open from an event callback it will act the same way as a link with target "_blank" opening a new tab or window depending on the user settings of the browser. If you call it anywhere else it will open a new window with a non-editable address bar and will not respect any of the settings you pass it.

Not sure if it's a bug or feature but there isn't any documentation on it that I can find explaining the reasoning.

Comment: it definitely is, Firefox works fine and from memory IE does as well but for some reason the Chrome developers decided to not implement it fully

Answer (score 0):

You can open a link in a new tab using `onClick`  `<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');">Google</a>` or simply `<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>`